# Issues with Eclipse installation on Solaris 11

Tags: eclipse, solaris

I downloaded Eclipse and extracted it to /opt directory. When i execute eclipse from terminal it say :

Cannot find /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

documentation in eclipse/readme/readme_eclipse.html says :

**Solaris**

This version of Eclipse works best with the latest version of GTK+ 2, but the earliest version supported is GTK+ 2.10.

The GTK libraries must be available on the library path (i.e. LD_LIBRARY_PATH).

Comment: If you don't have a strong IDE preference then you may get more joy using Netbeans on Solaris.

Comment: Thanks Paul Floyd.

Answer (score 2):

`Cannot find /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` indicates you downloaded a Linux binary, not a Solaris one.  You'll need to download a version built for Solaris instead.

Comment: It appears that Solaris ceased to be an official platform when Eclipse 4 came out.  Eclipse 3.8.2 appears to be the latest.  If this in anyway misbehaves then go for Netbeans or IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks Alanc and Andersen